# Update changes made to Activity from different Screens (Activity Stacking)

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

In my application I have Activities that effect other ones. An example is on the profile page changing the name or other data. When I am done making changes I click the save button which finishes the application and the profile screen is shown again.

The profile screen does not reflect the new changes because it is coming from the below stack. How is the best practice for getting the refreshed version of this profile screen without creating a new intent and instance of the Activity.

(this sort of thing happens all over the place in the application)

Comment: You should use jetpack livedata to change values live https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Answer (score 1):

You should not "save" data like this (via intent extras). 
Use local db (Realm, Room) so you can always save it and retrieve it from any screen.